# Unable to install bpl after building it in project upgraded from C++ Builder 2010 to C++ Builder 10 Seattle

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010, bpl, c++builder-10-seattle

I have a large project group I'm in the process of updating from C++ Builder 2010 to Seattle. So quite a jump :) I have run into several issues and managed to solve them all but yesterday I scratched my head a bit. One project builds a bpl used by other parts of the system. After some minor code tweaks it compiles fine but when I right-click the project to "install" the bpl I get an error message saying

> The procedure entry point
>   @TLanguageDialog@$bctr$qqrp25System@Classes@TComponent could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library TranslationTools.bpl

TComponent is part of the VCL library if I remember correctly so I'm trying to figure out what the issue here is and how to solve it. Has something in the way bpl's are constructed changed so it's expecting something that didn't use to be there or what? As said it compiles just fine, but just in case here are the settings for the include and lib paths.

Include: **$(BDSINCLUDE)\windows\vcl;$(BDSINCLUDE)\windows\vcl\design**

Lib: **$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\$(Config);$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\Release\psdk**

Comment: The error is saying that the installed BPL has a link to an exported `__fastcall TLanguageDialog(TComponent*)` constructor in `TranslationTools.bpl`, but the loader is not able to find that exported constructor in `TranslationTools.bpl` when the installed BPL is being loaded.  Make sure that `TranslationTools.bpl` is being compiled correctly, that it really has the export present (use `TDUMP` to confirm), that there is not another conflicting version of `TranslationTools.bpl` on the system search path, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution ended up being rouge **bpl** files like Remy sugested. **bpl** files had ended up in **System32**. Although all installed **bpl** files had been uninstalled in the **IDE** a version of the build project was once installed to the system and wrote bpl files to **System32** which caused the **IDE** to try and use these and not my newly compiled ones.